Store purged data into a file in local SQL Server
I have a stored procedure like as below. When I pass 90 as storage period days parameter, then the procedure will keep 90 days data and purge remaining all the data from cp.info, cp.file_. My requirement is to store the purged data into local server in the form of CSV format where SQL Server is installed.
like, table_date format. eg: info_2024-03-29
In future if client wants to restore the old data, then I can use those data files.
I am using SQL Server web edition and the details are below
Product: Microsoft SQL Server 2019
Edition: Web Edition (64-bit)
Version: 15.0.4345.5
Release: RTM-CU24 (Cumulative Update 24)
Build date: December 4, 2023
Copyright: Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation
Operating System: Linux (Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS)



create or alter procedure [dp].[dp#purge_objects_data]
 @i_storage_period_days    bigint
 
 as 
 begin
 set nocount    on;
 set xact_abort on;
 drop table if exists #dp_root_run_ids;
 create table #dp_root_run_ids( run_id bigint, enddate datetime2);
 WITH cte_run_ids as (
 select distinct id, enddate from cp.run_ids where status='COMPLETED')
 insert into #dp_root_run_ids
         ( id
         , end_date
         )
    select rrun.id
         , rrun.enddate as end_date
    from cte_run_ids rrun
    where rrun.enddate < dateAdd( day, -1 * @i_storage_period_days, cast(getUTCDate() as date));

DELETE FROM cp.info where run_id in (select distinct id from #dp_root_run_ids);
DELETE from cp.file_ where run_id in (select distinct id from #dp_root_run_ids);
end

How we can achieve this in SQL Server.
Thanks

This sounds kinda weird , why not just move the records to another table/database? It's not like you're gaining any space

Or soft delete the records?

We are purging the data to save some space, SQL server is allocated with very limited space around 15 GB.

Just use your backups if you need to restore data?

To restore the data first i need to save the deleted data into csv file right? so how to save them in local?

Acquire or allocate more storage to either expand the current database or allocate a new historic data database, with the same structure to receive archived/deleted data.  Storage is cheap - much cheaper than  the effort required to design and implement an offline file-base repository. (Compare the cost per TB of disk storage vs the hourly wage for a good programmer or DBA.)

If you are running a production database I truly hope you are taking regular database backups (which are not CSV files).

There's nothing out of the box for csv backup based storage. You'd have to export your data into csv using powershell or whatnot and hope there are no newlines or other things like quotes in the middle of the text or escape them yourselves. I agree about the backups, it's the best solution, take regular backups and put them into a more voluminous storage facility
